# Finding probability mass function of sequence of flips of coins

Tags: probability

Suppose a fair coin is continually flipped until head appears for the 10th times. Let $X$ denote the number of tails that occur. Compute the pmf of $X$.

### Attempt

Let's try for $X=0$, this means that we have just $10$ heads. Thus, $P(X=0)$ is the probaility of obtaining $10$ heads and this is just $\frac{1}{2^{10}}$.

Now, how about $X=1$? Well in this case we have $10$ heads plus 1 tail, and there are $10$ possible ways that tails can occur in between the ten tails. That is $P(X=1) = 10 \cdot \frac{1}{2^{10}} \cdot \frac{1}{2^{11}} $.

Now, for the case $X=x$ now we have $10$ heads and $x$ tails so we wanna choose $x$ tails out $10+x$. So,

$$ P(X=x) = {10+x \choose x } \frac{1}{2^x} \frac{1}{2^{10}}$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mostly there.     It is *not* just 10 heads and $x$ tails.   The event of $\{X=x\}$ is a result of *some arrangement* of $9$ heads and $x$ tails, and then *the last roll* is the tenth head.   Adjust your answer to account for that.

Also, note, it is powers of $2$ in the denominator, not of $10$.   Important!

Now, consider $X=1$.   There are 10 ways to arrange 10 heads and 1 tails, *however* one of those ways is the event $X=0$ (when the tail is in the eleventh place, there are no tails before the tenth head).  So there are only *nine* arrangements for $X=1$, and the probaility is $9\cdot 2^{-11}$

And so on.   The argument you made was otherwise spot on, so you can complete this.

---

Every probability mass function also includes the support, which in this case is the entire Natural Numbers.   Make a note of that too.

Comment: I think for $X=1$ we have $P(X=1) = 10 \frac{1}{2^{11}}$. Because we must have sequences of the form $THHH...H$, $HTH...H$,... $HH...HTH$. So withouth counting the last one which must alwas be $H$, we have $10$ previous fliips and we are arranging the T in between then which is done in $10$ ways: ${10 \choose 1 }$.